# How is the hidden layer size determined for MLPRegressor in SciKitLearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

Lets say I'm creating a neural net using the following code:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

model = MLPRegressor(
  hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),
  activation='identity'
)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For the `hidden_layer_sizes`, I simply set it to the default. However, I don't really understand how it works. What is the number of hidden layers in my definition? Is it 100?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html):

> **hidden_layer_sizes : *tuple, length = n_layers - 2, default (100,)***
>
> The ith element represents the number of neurons in the ith hidden layer.

It is `length = n_layers - 2`, because the number of your hidden layers is the total number of layers `n_layers` minus 1 for your input layer, minus 1 for your output layer.

In your (default) case of `(100,)`, it means one hidden layer of 100 units (neurons).

For 3 hidden layers of, say, 100, 50, and 25 units respectively, it would be

```
hidden_layer_sizes = (100, 50, 25)
```

See the [example in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#classification) (it is for `MLPClassifier`, but the logic is identical).